# Understandin how rename images scrapy works

Tags: python, scrapy

I see all questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rename%20images%20scrapy), but i dont understand yet.

Actualy with de code bellow i do what i need, except rename de image, so i try change name in the `items.py` file, pls check comments inside.

**settings.py**

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['xxx.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'xxx.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/magicnt/xxx/images'
```

**items.py**

```
class XxxItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    #images = scrapy.Field()<---with that code work with default name images
    images = title<--- I try rename here, but not work
```

spider.py

```
from xxx.items import XxxItem
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class CoverSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pyimagesearch-cover-spider"
    start_urls = ['https://xxx.com.br/product']
    def parse(self, response):
        for bimb in response.css('#mod_imoveis_result'):
            imageURL = bimb.xpath('./div[@id="g-img-imo"]/div[@class="img_p_results"]/img/@src').extract_first()
            title = bimb.css('#titulo_imovel::text').extract_first()
            yield {
                'image_urls' : [response.urljoin(imageURL)],
                'title' : title
            }
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "num_pages") and contains(@class, "pg_number_next")]/@href').extract_first()
        yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

My goal is rename downloaded images with the title from item. Any tip for this goal are welcome.

I'm totally new to python and oo, I usually scrape with structural php but realize what a good scrapy it can be, ask for a little patience and help.

Comment: Negative are welcome, any tip for made this question better? Not clear, no code, whats happens?

Answer (score 3):

My code is based on [Scrapy Image Pipeline: How to rename images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353047/scrapy-image-pipeline-how-to-rename-images) I tested it a week ago and it works on my own spiders.

```
# This pipeline is designed for an item with multiple images
class ImagesWithNamesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        # values in field "image_name" must have suffix ".jpg"
        # you can only change "image_name" to your own image name filed "images"
        # however it should be a list
        for (image_url, image_name) in zip(item[self.IMAGES_URLS_FIELD], item["image_names"]):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=image_url, meta={"image_name": image_name})

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        image_name = request.meta["image_name"]
        return image_name
```

---

Here is how the `ImagePipeline` works:

The pipeline will execute `image_downloaded` -> `get_images` -> `file_path` in order. ("->" means invokes)

- `image_downloaded`: save images that `get_images` return by invoking `persist_file`
- `get_images`: convert images to JPEG
- `file_path`: return the **relative path** of image

I scaned through [the source code of ImagePipeline](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/images.py) and found no special field for rename an image. Scrapy will rename it in this way:

```
def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    image_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()  # change to request.url after deprecation
    return 'full/%s.jpg' % (image_guid)
```

Therefore we should override method `file_path`. According to [the source code of FilePipeline](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py) which ImagePipeline inherits, we only need to return **relative paths** and `persist_file` will get things done.